# How does a Gaussian Process define a probability distribution in the functions space?

Tags: stochastic-processes, machine-learning, gaussian

I am studying Gaussian Process Regression. I will post a text from the book Gaussian Process for Machine Learning, by C. E. Rasmussen & C. K. I. Williams:

*We first consider a simple 1-d regression problem, mapping from an input x to an output f (x). In Figure 1.1 (a) we show a number of sample functions drawn at random from the prior distribution over functions specified by a particular Gaussian process which favors smooth functions. This prior is taken to represent our prior beliefs over the kinds of functions we expect to observe, before seeing any data.*

The definition of a Gaussian process that I know of is given by:

Definition (Gaussian process) A random process $\left(X_{t}\right)_{t \in T}$ is called a Gaussian process if, for any finite subset $T_{0} \subset T,$ the random vector
$$
\left(X_{t}\right)_{t \in T_{0}}
$$
has normal distribution. Equivalently, $\left(X_{t}\right)_{t \in T}$ is Gaussian if every finite linear combination
$$
\sum_{t \in T_{0}} a_{t} X_{t}
$$
is a normal random variable.

I would like to better understand the connection of this definition with the possibility of defining a distribution in the functions space, because to draw functions according to a distribution, I would have to define sigma algebras in the function space and a measure of probability in this sigma algebra. Or perhaps there is another meaning when we say "sample functions drawn at random from the prior distribution over functions specified by a particular Gaussian process".

Does anyone help to build this bridge?

Comment: Does this post answer your question ? : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376141/what-is-a-distribution-over-functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that a stochastic process defines a function-valued random variable is simple enough. Say you have $X : \Omega \times T \to \mathbb{R}$. Then you can consider the mapping $\omega \mapsto (t \mapsto X(\omega,t))$ to be a function-valued random variable: for each fixed $\omega$ you have a function that maps $T$ into $\mathbb{R}$. In shorthand you would call this function $X(\omega,\cdot)$.

It's the other matters, about what the $\sigma$-algebra on the function space is and what the probability measure is, that are more technical. Rather than going into all these details here, I will simply say that:

- the usual $\sigma$-algebra on function spaces is the one generated by the so-called cylindric sets, which take the form $\{ \omega : X(\omega,t_0) \in I \}$ where $t_0$ is a fixed element of $T$ and $I$ is an interval.
- the probability measure on the cylindric sets can be shown to exist by using the so-called Kolmogorov extension theorem, once you have the finite dimensional distributions of the process.

Comment: The technical details are omitted here, as you say. Perhaps this (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4662917/in-what-way-is-a-gaussian-process-a-distribution-over-function-space), similar but more measure-oriented, question is a good place to put them?